# Is anonymous function expression?

Tags: javascript, expression, anonymous-function

Is an anonymous function expression? if it is, why can not we use it wherever JavaScript expects an expression?

Example :

```
const result = String(function () {
    return 2;
});
```

what  variable returns :

```
'function () {\r\n    return 2;\r\n}'
```

but I expected to get 2 in string format because if anonymous function is expression it must return 2 as the argument for the String function

I tried to use an anonymous function where js expects an expression but i did not get the result what i expected

Comment: `String` is not going to execute the function. It just takes the argument and turns it into a string.

Comment: You never invoke the function, you just define it. You could invoke it with the following: `String(function () { return 2;} ())`

Comment: Everyone that has commented/answered here is correct as to why your code isn't working as expected, but to answer your question "Is an anonymous function an expression" - the answer is no. Anonymous vs named is not what makes a function a function expression. [See the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) for clarification

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to *invoke* the function.  A function definition by itself is just that, a definition.  If it's never invoked, it won't return the value.

(And interpreting a function definition as a string results in the text of the function, which is the result you're observing.)

```js
const result = String(function () {
    return 2;
}()); // Note the additional () here
console.log(result);
```